# Configuring ssl in rabbitmq.config using rabbitmq docker image

Tags: bash, ssl, docker, rabbitmq, docker-compose

My goal is to set rabbitmq with ssl support, which was achieved previously using below `rabbitmq.config` file, which resides in host's `/etc/rabbitmq` path.

Now I want to be able to configure other rabbitmq user and password than  defaults `guest` `guest`.

I'm using rabbitmq docker image with following docker-compose configuration:

```
version: '2'
services:
    rabbitmq:
        build: ./rabbitmq
        ports:
          - "8181:8181"
        expose:
          - "15672"
          - "8181"
        volumes:
          - /etc/rabbitmq:/etc/rabbitmq

        environment:
          RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: user123
          RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: 1234
```

**Rabbitmq config**:

```erlang
[{rabbit,
  [
    {loopback_users, []},
    {heartbeat,0},
    {ssl_listeners, [8181]},
    {ssl_options, [{cacertfile, "/etc/rabbitmq/ca/cacert.pem"},
                   {certfile,   "/etc/rabbitmq/server/cert.pem"},
                   {keyfile,    "/etc/rabbitmq/server/key.pem"},
                   {verify,verify_none},
                   {fail_if_no_peer_cert,false}]}
  ]}
].
```

**Rabbitmq dockerfile**:

```
from rabbitmq:management

#and some certificate generating logic
```

I noticed that once upon adding `environment` section, current `rabbitmq.config` file is overriden with auto generated configuration possibly by [docker-entrypoint.sh file](https://github.com/docker-library/rabbitmq/blob/79277042564875d55e4b05a60c65b6eb46651a94/3.6/debian/docker-entrypoint.sh#L12).

For building configuration using the certs I found environment variables that can do this (look [here](https://github.com/docker-library/rabbitmq/issues/138)).
However didn't found any reference for defining `ssl_listeners` section with its port, as seen in below `rabbitmq.config`

**My question is**: how can I create the exact configuration as mentioned below using env variables **OR** how can I remain with mine `rabbitmq.config` defining rabbitmq with new user and password in some dynamic way (maybe templating the config file)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
version: '2'
services:
    rabbitmq:
        build: ./rabbitmq
        ports:
          - "8181:8181"
        expose:
          - "15672"
          - "8181"
        volumes:
          - /etc/rabbitmq:/etc/rabbitmq
        command: rabbitmq-server
        entrypoint: ""
        environment:
          RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: user123
          RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: 1234
```

This will override the `docker-entrpoint` and just run the rabbitmq server. Now the `./docker-entrypoint.sh` sets certain environment variables also. Which may be needed in your case. So to make sure you have everything needed

Comment: The output of this solution is equivalent to not writing the environment section at all, since docker entrypoint is using these to add user which is different than guest default user.

Comment: Then next option is to copy the docker-entrypoint.sh and customize it based on your need and then share it using a volume mapping in docker-compose to override the file while loading the image. You can choose this approach if you want

Comment: If you give environment variables such as mentioned in above link, and not overriding entrypoint than `rabbitmq.config` is being re-created according to environment section.

Comment: Ok ,I see, can you please provide an example for that?
By the way what about using a template config file and filling it with env variables values, can you think of how can we do this?